# Why do the movie posters show Katniss in red?

Tags: the-hunger-games, the-hunger-games-mockingjay-2

We know from watching the movies that Cinna created the Mockingjay outfit in black. In the MJ2 movie posters, Katniss is most often shown as wearing deep red. Is there a significance to this? Was there anything put out in the press or online which tells us why they designed the posters this way? It is a distinct change from the coloring of the MJ1 movie posters.

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The posters follow the other extra-canon media presented to boost demand and anticipation for the film. This includes blogs, websites, games and video propaganda ***as if it were made in-universe***. This is a viral marketing concept called [In-Universe Marketing over at TV Tropes](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/InUniverseMarketing) (Also [Alternative Reality Game](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/AlternateRealityGame).) Transformers did it in a particularly big way.

Hunger Games has made excellent use of this through all four movies. [The propaganda posters released by *"The Capitol"* for Mockingjay Part 1 were pretty sweet.](http://www.cinemablend.com/new/Can-You-Spot-What-Wrong-With-Posters-From-Hunger-Games-Mockingjay-Part-1-43528.html) This propaganda all shows Katniss in a red mockingjay battle suit.

[image]

This image is on both a propaganda video and the revolution's website http://www.Revolution.pn.

[image]

Note that this poster image is used on the Captiol's website http://www.Capitol.pn, ***as if District 13 had hacked into the site and defaced it with Revolution Propaganda***.

[image]

Much of Mockingjay (1 and 2) has cold war themes, including the reliance on Propaganda both by the Rebellion and the Capitol. Each interview with Peeta in Part 1 was in-universe propaganda, and [District 13 attempts to make CGI propaganda with Katniss reading lines (How a Revolution Dies)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WDakdlKt1GM). They go with live battle-field [footage that was much better (Fire is Catching, If we burn you burn with us)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WK3hBvk5ees). **The real world posters reflect that in-universe propaganda**. The Capitol has it's own propaganda as well. It's all a method of immersing the audience into the world of the film, of world building, as well as getting cans in the seats.

Of course,

> She does not wear a Red suit at all in the on-screen material.

Comment: I often wonder about the language of cinema being largely unknown to the current generation. One aspect would be the acceptance of promotional, non-filmic material. When I was a child, the posters for the remake of King Kong showed Kong with one foot on the top of each of the towers. Even as a kid I realised this was a promotional exaggeration. A modern example would be the montage shots taken for each season of The Sopranos, showing all of the main characters together in a way that never happened in any of the episodes.